# Given a directory, get relative paths of all files recursively

Tags: bash, centos, rpmbuild

I'm building an RPM spec file and need to list in the `%files` section the files to include, relative to a build root that I'll specify. I already have the assembled directory that needs to be packaged--I just need to turn this into a list of relative paths to all files contained therein.

To do this I'm currently using `find`, but it's returning absolute paths.

```
find $1/codebase -type f ! -name ".*" >> ${BUILD_RPM_DST_DIR}/rpm.spec
```

I'm a bit of a unix n00b so I apologize.

Should I pipe it to sed or grep and remove the initial portion of the path? A sample of how to do that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find will give you relative paths, if you pass a relative specification to it when you run it.  You are passing `$1/codebase` which I gather is an absolute path.  Instead of using that command try something like `cd $1/codebase ; find . -type ...` instead.